# How to create a graph / network with given average shortest path and average degree value?

Tags: r, graph, networkx, igraph, shortest-path

I want to create a graph (preferably using igraph on R) with a given value of average degree and shortest path.

Basically, I want a toy image to demonstrate that both variables are independent. I want to generate [a figure like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx4rt.png) but for a bigger number of nodes and for a specific value of shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

Some very simple examples are given by rings (like in your example) and fully connected graphs.  All nodes in a ring have degree 2, but you can make examples with shortest path as big as you like.

```
n=11
Ring = make_ring(n)
LO = layout_with_fr(Ring)
plot(Ring, layout=LO)
```

[image: Ring Graph]

You can adjust the mean shortest path by adjusting n. For example:

```
n=9
Ring = make_ring(n)
mean_distance(Ring)
[1] 2.5

n=13
Ring = make_ring(n)
mean_distance(Ring)
[1] 3.5
```

In a fully connected graph,  the shortest path always has length 1 but you can make the degree as big as you like.

```
FG = make_full_graph(n)
plot(FG, layout=LO)
```

[image: Full Graph]

Comment: Thanks! This is a good idea but the problem is that I would like to show specific shortest path value (I want to compare two situations with shortest path 2.5 and 3.5) and show and example with these values.

Comment: You say that you want (average) shortest path = 2.5 & 3.5. What do you want for degree?  Just anything different from those numbers?

Comment: As degree I don't mind so much. The only important thing is that it should be same degree for both networks.

Comment: The above examples with rings have shortest path = 2.5 & 3.5 (n=9 & n-13)and both rings have degree = 2.